# recarga pagina despues oprimir un boton por defaul

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

hola ya he intentado muchas maneras tengo estas dos  `function` de dos botones diferentes los cuales al oprimirlos me lleva a `index0_1.php` hasta ahí todo bien pero lo que quiero es que dependiendo del botón cuando se cargue la pagina se oprima el botón con un `$().click();` pero no lo hace solo carga la pagina como puedo solucionar eso?

```
$("#solicitud_incorporacion").click(function() { 
    location.href="index0_1.php";
    $("frm_solicitud").click(); 
}); 

$("#consulta_incorporacion").click(function() { 
    location.href="index0_1.php";
    $("frm_consulta").click(); 

});
```

Comment: `location.href` carga la URL que le das inmediatamente. El evento click que pones después se pierde porque se carga la nueva página con sus recursos y eventos. Envíale un parámetro en la URL, en cookies o en la sesión para que la página destino sepa qué evento esperas que se dispare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que al ejecutar el location.href el navegador se va a otra página y en ese momento ya pierde el control del DOM.

Lo que puedes hacer para resolver tu problema es enviar un parametro mediante la url de la siguiente manera:

```
$("#solicitud_incorporacion").click(function() { 
    location.href="index0_1.php?click=frm_solicitud";
});
```

> En la pagina index0_1.php

En esta página deberías tener un codigo como este:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var c = url.searchParams.get("click");

if (c === frm_solicitud) {
  $("#frm_solicitud").click(); //cambie este selector porq creo que te falto poner el # que hace referencia al id
}
```

Recuerda que este codigo javascript debe encontrarse antes de cerrar el body de la página o dentro de un document.ready

Comment: Gracias me sirvió